# How to use wcf service in desktop application with one stance for one session

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

I am working on wcf services i have a wcf service project, and it is hosted in Asp.Net website, by this website i have added service reference in my desktop application (C# 4.0).

The services is :

```
namespace Web100Service
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class SmsService : ISmsService
    {
        int Counter = 0;
        public int AddCounter()
        {
            return Counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make one instance of this service for each time application start, and it should be available until the application do not close.

but when i am using it in desktop application, variable Counter become zero after calling AddCounter.
How can i achinve this task

Comment: Why keep an instance lingering? In general, treat this as you would a database context: do your unit of work then get out of there, fast! You open up a host of things to concern yourself with when leaving it around.

Comment: When my application starts, i make some variables, and fetchs some information from database (it takes time), i dont want to make this variables each time i call the service methods

Answer (score 0):

What binding are you using? Not all bindings support sessions. Also, make sure the session timeout is long enough that you don't accidentally create a new session after a few minutes.

Comment: OK - BasicHttp does not support sessions, so the variables will not be retained between calls. You may use wsHttpBinding, NetTcp, or any other binding that support sessions. Here is more info. http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/wcf-sessions/